# Understanding filters injection within tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, filter

I've started to watch [a tutorial video series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFYID8eYQLs&list=PLP6DbQBkn9ymGQh2qpk9ImLHdSH5T7yw7) on youtube about angularJS. And in the video called Testing Overview, John Lindquist creates an app like this :

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.filter('reverse', function(){
    return function(text)
    {
         return text.split("").reverse().join("");
    }
})
function firstCtrl($scope, Data){
    $scope.data = Data;
}
```

Then he creates a unit-test with Karma and Jasmine like this :

```
describe('filter', function()
{
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    describe('reverse', function()
    {
        it('should reverse a string', inject(function(reverseFilter) {
            expect(reverseFilter('ABCD')).toEqual('DCBA');
        }))
    })
})
```

The test passes, the code is ok, but I cannot find out why.

I made my own copy of this in order to understand where the maggic happens ... And  having heard about this parameter-naming thing with AngularJS, I changed `inject(function(reverseFilter)` to `inject(function(anytext)` and it stopped working, as expected.

Then I noticed that if I rename my filter like so `myApp.filter('foe', function()`, the inject call has to be done with `inject(function(foeFilter)`.

Where does this come from ? AngularJs' injection system seems to be using some camelcase to concatenate 'Filter' to the filter's name, but I cannot find any documentation about this procedure anywhere. I also find 'amusing' that using `inject(function(foe)` does not work, whereas matching the parameter name with the relative dependency seems to be the simplest way to get hold of dependencies in AngularJS. Does AngularJS do this with other types of dependencies ?

Any help would be appreciated.

You can see an example of testing a filter this way in the angularJs official tutorial [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09#test).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with filters angular concatenates 'Filter' to the name.  They also do this with providers.  When you create a provider using `$provide` or `module.provide` you can access the provider in the config block by appending 'Provider' to the name.  I'm not 100% sure for the reason, but this way angular can be sure that something you inject into the config block has indeed been configured as a provider (or a constant) and in the case of filters, when you use them in your html

`<div ng-repeat="stuff in things | filter:model"></div>`

angular can be sure to look for a filter called 'filterFilter'.  If you were to put a service called filter there, it wouldn't work, so angular wanted to allow for creating filters and services by the same defined name, while saving them by slightly different names.  Does that help?